# Subversion listing changes between URLs

Tags: svn, diff, summary, tortoisesvn

I am  looking for a way of easily listing changes between two URLs in subversion, listing the files that have changed , when , who and why.

Using Totoise  either gives you too much detail, showing the actual source code changes or too little i.e. it lists the files that have changed without the reason , when and why ("message").

I am  trying to summarise the changes between two tags /releases

Comment: So you don't want the whole details and neither the summary. What then? You said, you were trying. What were you trying?

Comment: Agree with goreSplatter, suggest that you actually provide an example of the kind of output you are hoping to see.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mind using the command line client? You might have to install it.

```
C> REM Doing below, so it'll fit in the comment box
C> set PROJ_URL=http://svn/repo/proj1

C> svn diff --summarize %PROJ_URL%/tags/REL-1.0 %PROJ_URL%/tags/REL-2.0
```

That'll show you the difference between the two URLs without the deep program details.

---

If you're talking about taking a log between the two revisions (seeing who changed what, etc), you can use `svn log -v --stop-on-copy` to find the revision and source of that tag:

```
C> svn set PROJ_URL=http://svn/repo/proj1
C> svn log -v --stop-on-copy %PROJ_URL%/tags/REL-1.0
r72342 | weintraubh | 2010-12-01 13:02:00 -0500 (Wed, 01 Dec 2010) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
    A /tags/REL-2.0 (from /trunk:72399)

Release 2.0
    r74384 | weintraubh | 2010-12-01 13:02:00 -0500 (Wed, 01 Dec 2010) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
    A /tags/REL-2.0 (from /trunk:74383)

Release 2.0
```

Ah! We now see that both tags come from trunk and REL-1.0 is revision 72399 and REL-2.0 is revision 74383

```
C> svn log -r72399:74383 -v
[listing of all changes...]
```

I actually wrote a PHP script to do this, so I could automatically produce a webpage listing the differences. I would gather the programs that were changed, and the Jira defects.

Unfortunately, I was laid off from that company, and then it went belly up a few weeks later. *(Moral to companies: Lay me off at your own risk.)* I can't get you the actual PHP code. However, it didn't take me more than a couple of days to write, and I don't even know PHP.